# Unable to upload GeoJSON file to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, coordinates, itunes, geojson

I'm getting the following error:

*"The JSON file you uploaded was invalid. Errors : Each set of coordinates provided must be valid"*

The Contents of the file are:

```
{ "type" : "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
                    [[[19.5,-99.1], [19.5,-99.2], [19.3,-99.2], [19.2,-99.1], [19.2,-98.9], [19.3,-98.9], [19.5,-99.0]]]
                    ]
}
```

I really can't find whats wrong, it works perfectly on the Simulator.

Any ideas ?

Comment: forgot to mention... in the iOS simulator works just fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied swaped the order of the coordinates, as in the Apple Docs. And made the start and ending coordinates equal.

Answer (score 1):

The order of Coordinate in GEOJSON is **[longitude, latitude]** :)

You can check more detail on: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#appendix-a-geometry-examples

or validate your geoJSON on: http://geojsonlint.com

Hope it is helpful.